# .htaccess dynamic links rewrite engine

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need your help creating some links using mod_rewrite.

I have some pages like:

- `register.php`
- `login.php`

And have the code for them:

```
RewriteRule    ^register/?$    register.php    [NC,L]    
RewriteRule    ^login/?$    login.php    [NC,L]
```

My problem is with "dynamic" links I have since I can't get them working.

For exemple I have links like:

```
index.php?id=news
índex.php?id=news&article=2
```

How can I transform those links into:

```
/news/
/news/article_name
```

And I have some products (that could have the same name in the same category) but with different ID's like:

```
índex.php?id=products&p=30
```

How can I change it to

```
/products/product-name
```

After this, is it possible to "generate" an unique name? Since I would like not set in the link the unique ID like `products/45342/product-name`?

What are the changes I need to make to my code to work with those links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example I have links like:

To clarify, you must first change the links in your application to be of the form `/news/` or `/news/article_name` (but see below). You then rewrite these "pretty" URLs back to the underlying filesystem path.

So, to rewrite `/news/` back to `index.php?id=news` you can do something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(news)/$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Using the `$1` backreference just saves typing. Only use the `NC` flag if this must be a case-sensitive match, but note that this potentially creates *duplicate content*, so you must specify the canonical URL in some other way (eg. `rel="canonical"` link element). For the same reason, only make the trailing slash optional if this is a specific requirement.

However, it's not possible to rewrite `/news/article_name` back to `index.php?id=news&article=2` (I assume that should be `i`, and not `í`, as in your question?) since the article ID (ie. `2`) is not present in the source URL. You need to include the ID in the source URL (or make the `article_name` unique and a key in your lookup). It would be more usual to create a URL like `/news/2/article_name` (which is what StackOverflow does), which can be easily rewritten. The `article_name` in the URL is purely for users (and indirect SEO). In which case you could rewrite this like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(news)/(\d+)/ index.php?id=$1&article=$2 [L]
```

This will rewrite `/news/N/<anything>` to `/index.php?id=news&article=N` (where `N` is 1 or more digits).

However, since it rewrites `<anything>` you should also implement a *redirect* in your *application* when the non-canonical `article_name` is accessed. (Which again, is what StackOverflow does.)

> And I have some products (that could have the same name in the same category) but with different ID's like: `índex.php?id=products&p=30`
>
> How can I change it to `/products/product-name`

The same principle as mentioned above applies here also.

> After this, is possible to "generate" an unique name?

You can generate this "unique name" in your application, not `.htaccess`. Build you URLs in your application etc.

> Since I would like not set in the link the unique ID like "products/45342/product-name" ?

As mentioned above, either your `product-name` is unique, and behaves like your *id*. Or you incorporate the unique ID in the URL - this is the far more common approach, offers greatest flexibility and is less prone to error. A "short" URL like `/products/45342` will redirect you to the correct *canonical* URL.